# How can I make a label with a message appear for a few seconds, and then the label is deleted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, label

I want to make a button so that a label appears with a small message, and after a while the message is deleted. I tried to do it with time.sleep () inside a def, which is activated by another def, but it doesn't work for me, because the message appears after a few seconds, while the button remains pressed, and the label is not deleted, can you help me fix it? :(

```
def salir():
    if trad["text"]!="ar.ab.iz.":
        #msg.showinfo("No","Ese no era el camino...")
        
        trad.config(text=leta)
        noes()

    else:
        codigo=tk.Toplevel(ventana)
        codigo.title("Salida")
        codigo.geometry("200x200")
        Label(codigo, text ="Encontré algo...").pack()
        caja = tk.Entry(codigo,textvariable="")
        caja.place(x=100,y=150)
        canvas.delete(ima)
        posx2 = 247
        posy2 = 100
        ima2 = canvas.create_image(247,780,image=myimg)
        trad.config(text=leta)
        new_windw=tk.Toplevel()

def noes():
    no=tk.Label(ventana, text ="Ese no era el camino...",font=("Verdana",20),bg="#148870", fg="white")
    no.place(relx = 0.5,rely = 0.4,anchor ='s')
    time.sleep(3)
    widget.forget()

boton2 = tk.Button(text="  Ir  ",font=("Verdana",16), command=salir)
boton2.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton2.place(x=746,y=379)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I discovered a command called after that is easier to use.

root.after (2000, label.destroy)

"root" (it is the name of the window in which you put the label), "2000" is the time equivalent to 2 seconds, "label" is the label you want to create, and "destroy" destroys it.

```
def button_pressed():
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!")
    label.pack()
    root.after(2000, label.destroy)


root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Press Button", command=button_pressed)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```